# Visual studio 2022 is freezing up when loading view if a breakpoint is set in the backend code(c#)

Tags: visual-studio

When I debug a web app in VS 2022, I have to reboot my computer every time I stop debugging.  If I don't, then when I try to debug again the browser opens and the page shows but the icon in the tab just spins and you have no control over the page.  you have to stop VS, reboot and then it works.  once i stop the debugger or the code hits and exception, I have to exit from VS and reboot otherwise I can't debug again.  I'm using Visual Studio 2022  17.5.1(latest) and i'm on windows 10.

any thoughts?

After talking with co-workers who have the same problem it looks like setting a breakpoint in the c# code is causing VS 2022 to freeze when loading a view.

Comment: I don't know if VS2022 still has this option but there is a command bar button in VS2019 called "Terminate All" that I use rather than the standard Shift-F5 (Stop Debugging). Failing that make sure the debugging process is terminated (look in Task Manager) before starting up another debug session.

Answer (score 2):

for now I've found a work around.  It looks like it's the JavaScript debugging that is causing the problem.  I went into Debug Options and unchecked the Enable javascript debugging options.  Now I can run the web app in debug and place breakpoints in the C# code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question could use some context to help the readers determine if it's applicable to their setup or not. Also, any specifics/details you can add will increase the community's useful answers